# Unifying "Is {language} on-topic?" questions under one tag scheme

Tags: discussion, tags, meta

Please can we unify all "is {language} on-topic?" questions to one tag scheme.

Since there are, with my counting at least, 35 such questions if we were to make this a tag then it would have more questions than [comments](/questions/tagged/comments), [broken-code](/questions/tagged/broken-code), [iterative-review](/questions/tagged/iterative-review) and [suggested-edits](/questions/tagged/suggested-edits).

---

### Questions

[scope](/questions/tagged/scope)[specific-language](/questions/tagged/specific-language)

- [discussion](/questions/tagged/discussion)[scope](/questions/tagged/scope) [Are questions about LaTeX documents on-topic?](https://codereview.meta.stackexchange.com/q/530)
- [discussion](/questions/tagged/discussion)[scope](/questions/tagged/scope)[specific-language](/questions/tagged/specific-language) [Is [lolcode] reviewable?](https://codereview.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2409)
- [discussion](/questions/tagged/discussion)[scope](/questions/tagged/scope)[tags](/questions/tagged/tags) [Are [vhdl] questions on-topic for Code Review?](https://codereview.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2461)
- [discussion](/questions/tagged/discussion)[scope](/questions/tagged/scope)[asking-questions](/questions/tagged/asking-questions) [Are we allowed to ask questions about just regular expressions?](https://codereview.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2562)
- [discussion](/questions/tagged/discussion)[scope](/questions/tagged/scope)[markdown](/questions/tagged/markdown) [Are questions to review markdown on-topic?](https://codereview.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5000)
- [discussion](/questions/tagged/discussion)[scope](/questions/tagged/scope)[images](/questions/tagged/images) [Are Scratch questions okay on Code Review?](https://codereview.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5923)
- [discussion](/questions/tagged/discussion)[scope](/questions/tagged/scope)[specific-question](/questions/tagged/specific-question)[specific-language](/questions/tagged/specific-language) [Nothing to review](https://codereview.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5947)
- [discussion](/questions/tagged/discussion)[scope](/questions/tagged/scope) [SQL Query Review](https://codereview.meta.stackexchange.com/q/7278)
- [discussion](/questions/tagged/discussion)[scope](/questions/tagged/scope) [What are the conditions for asking a Wolfram Mathematica question here?](https://codereview.meta.stackexchange.com/q/7315)
- [discussion](/questions/tagged/discussion)[scope](/questions/tagged/scope) [Are regex reviews allowed on this site?](https://codereview.meta.stackexchange.com/q/7337)
- [discussion](/questions/tagged/discussion)[scope](/questions/tagged/scope)[asking-questions](/questions/tagged/asking-questions) [Can I ask to review my ebuild or rpmspec file?](https://codereview.meta.stackexchange.com/q/8409)
- [discussion](/questions/tagged/discussion)[scope](/questions/tagged/scope) [Is a BNF grammar for a language acceptable for review as concrete code?](https://codereview.meta.stackexchange.com/q/8598)
- [discussion](/questions/tagged/discussion)[scope](/questions/tagged/scope) [Are Nix expressions without any logic on topic?](https://codereview.meta.stackexchange.com/q/9272)
- [discussion](/questions/tagged/discussion)[scope](/questions/tagged/scope)[asking-questions](/questions/tagged/asking-questions) [Is the review of vocabulary/ontology use (e.g., for HTML structured data) on-topic?](https://codereview.meta.stackexchange.com/q/9310)
- [discussion](/questions/tagged/discussion)[scope](/questions/tagged/scope) [Is GraphQL Reviewable?](https://codereview.meta.stackexchange.com/q/9414)

[scope](/questions/tagged/scope) but [specific-language](/questions/tagged/specific-language) seems incorrect.

- [discussion](/questions/tagged/discussion)[scope](/questions/tagged/scope)[site-policy](/questions/tagged/site-policy) [Why is pseudocode not allowed?](https://codereview.meta.stackexchange.com/q/525)
- [discussion](/questions/tagged/discussion) [Are UML diagram reviews on-topic for CodeReview?](https://codereview.meta.stackexchange.com/q/539)
- [discussion](/questions/tagged/discussion)[scope](/questions/tagged/scope)[site-policy](/questions/tagged/site-policy) [Is pseudo-code alright when asking about performance?](https://codereview.meta.stackexchange.com/q/594)
- [discussion](/questions/tagged/discussion)[scope](/questions/tagged/scope)[specific-question](/questions/tagged/specific-question)[projects](/questions/tagged/projects) [Is reviewing project structure on topic?](https://codereview.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1025)
- [discussion](/questions/tagged/discussion)[scope](/questions/tagged/scope)[asking-questions](/questions/tagged/asking-questions) [Questions about documentation](https://codereview.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1541)
- [discussion](/questions/tagged/discussion)[scope](/questions/tagged/scope)[specific-question](/questions/tagged/specific-question)[third-party](/questions/tagged/third-party) [Code requiring a third-party pre-processor to make it work](https://codereview.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1616)
- [discussion](/questions/tagged/discussion)[scope](/questions/tagged/scope) [Are reviews of protocols in scope here?](https://codereview.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1841)
- [discussion](/questions/tagged/discussion)[scope](/questions/tagged/scope) [Are Git workflow questions on-topic?](https://codereview.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1930)
- [discussion](/questions/tagged/discussion)[scope](/questions/tagged/scope)[specific-question](/questions/tagged/specific-question) [Can we review spreadsheet formulas?](https://codereview.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2118)
- [discussion](/questions/tagged/discussion)[scope](/questions/tagged/scope) [Can I ask for feedback on an idea for a standard?](https://codereview.meta.stackexchange.com/q/4973)
- [discussion](/questions/tagged/discussion)[scope](/questions/tagged/scope)[specific-question](/questions/tagged/specific-question) [CoreData or code-backed UML reviews](https://codereview.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5011)
- [discussion](/questions/tagged/discussion)[scope](/questions/tagged/scope) [Can I post Excel formulas for review here?](https://codereview.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5119)
- [discussion](/questions/tagged/discussion)[scope](/questions/tagged/scope)[asking-questions](/questions/tagged/asking-questions) [Asking questions with UML diagrams instead of code](https://codereview.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5398)
- [discussion](/questions/tagged/discussion)[scope](/questions/tagged/scope) [Can I request that someone look over my legal code?](https://codereview.meta.stackexchange.com/q/6593)
- [discussion](/questions/tagged/discussion)[scope](/questions/tagged/scope) [Non-code formula spreadsheet](https://codereview.meta.stackexchange.com/q/6730)
- [discussion](/questions/tagged/discussion)[scope](/questions/tagged/scope) [Transforming a similar concept into a code review](https://codereview.meta.stackexchange.com/q/6797)

[scope](/questions/tagged/scope) but is a collection of languages.

- [discussion](/questions/tagged/discussion)[scope](/questions/tagged/scope)[site-policy](/questions/tagged/site-policy) [Can graphical notation count as code or should questions with exclusively graphical notation be considered off topic?](https://codereview.meta.stackexchange.com/q/611)
- [discussion](/questions/tagged/discussion)[site-policy](/questions/tagged/site-policy)[asking-questions](/questions/tagged/asking-questions) [What's the proper way to ask for database review?](https://codereview.meta.stackexchange.com/q/843)
- [discussion](/questions/tagged/discussion)[scope](/questions/tagged/scope) [Esoteric vs Golfed Code](https://codereview.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2426)
- [discussion](/questions/tagged/discussion)[scope](/questions/tagged/scope) [Do configuration files constitute reviewable code?](https://codereview.meta.stackexchange.com/q/6060)

---

Given the amount of this type of question I believe that they should be categorized together in some form. At the very least it would help me when I search for questions.

I asked in chat about making a new tag, say [language-scope](/questions/tagged/language-scope), and was recommended to instead use both [scope](/questions/tagged/scope) and [specific-language](/questions/tagged/specific-language) together. At first I thought this was a good idea. And since [only these questions have been tagged that way](https://codereview.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/scope+specific-language) it's feasible. However after collecting and grouping all of these type of question, that I know of, together I'm not sure it makes the most sense.

How should we tag these questions, with [scope](/questions/tagged/scope)[language-scope](/questions/tagged/language-scope) or [scope](/questions/tagged/scope)[specific-language](/questions/tagged/specific-language)?

Comment: I agree with unifying and disagree with the new tag. Now I'm not sure what to vote...

Comment: The question is just asking for a unification. However it doesn't say which way to go, just my opinion. IMO upvote = agree with unification, downvote = disagree with unification. I'll post an answer with the tag to make it clearer.

Answer (score 2):

Unification is great! But we don't need a new tag for that.

All questions mentioning a language by name:
[discussion](/questions/tagged/discussion)[scope](/questions/tagged/scope)[specific-language](/questions/tagged/specific-language).

Yes, this only covers less than half of the questions you list. Honestly, I think those are among the most important questions of your list.

Especially [specific-language](/questions/tagged/specific-language) really sounds like it was made for (among others) this type of question. Besides, languages don't have a scope. The site has. So [language-scope](/questions/tagged/language-scope) is both counter-intuitive and ambiguous. I'm not a fan of using that.

All questions mentioning a specific question can be amended with [specific-question](/questions/tagged/specific-question).

Looking at the tag-wiki for [site-policy](/questions/tagged/site-policy) I think it shouldn't apply to those questions in general, unless it's about a question which was incorrectly closed. [tags](/questions/tagged/tags) looks misused as well.

I'm on the fence about [asking-questions](/questions/tagged/asking-questions). I think the current scope of that tag is too broad, but that's for another meta. It's kind of implied already with [scope](/questions/tagged/scope) and adds no new value, but might make it easier during a search.

Turns out that the list and the question title don't share the same load entirely, so the list has to be thinned out a bit too. We can unify "Is {language} on-topic/reviewable" questions, but some of the listed questions aren't about that it seems. At least, not in the sense of programming-language.

I'll concede it could apply in language as in the broader (and outside of CS more widely supported) definition. While I'm not sure we should use it as such on a purely programming-oriented site, I won't oppose it if there's community support. I just hope the tag won't get too broad to be useful.

Comment: I have seen questions that seem hypothetical that don't mention a language tag, such as just using the OOP tag.

Comment: @pacmaninbw It's unclear if you're talking about main or meta.

Comment: @pacmaninbw On main, hypothetical-code questions should be closed, their tags are irrelevant. If it turns out the code only looks that way, a proper tag can be applied. All questions should have a language tag. But this is about meta questions asking about whether a certain language is acceptable here.

Comment: I'm talking about Main. Is this discussion about Meta?

Comment: This is about meta tags... since the question is tagged meta and all the tags link to meta tags

Answer (score 1):

We should tag them with [scope](/questions/tagged/scope)[language-scope](/questions/tagged/language-scope)

**Note**: In case it's not been clear we're talking about *Meta tags*.

It should be noted that [Mast's answer](https://codereview.meta.stackexchange.com/a/10476) is in agreement with the groupings in the question. If the [language-scope](/questions/tagged/language-scope) tag is added it would incorporate Mast's suggestion. It seems my explanation on why [specific-language](/questions/tagged/specific-language) only fits on 11/28 questions was inadequate, and so I have expanded on it below.

---

## Collection of languages

The tag [specific-language](/questions/tagged/specific-language) is not a good fit for the last group of questions. This is because they're not asking about a specific language. They're asking about:

- Images
- Databases
- Esteric languages
- Configuration files

It should be clear that tagging any of these with [specific-language](/questions/tagged/specific-language) is wrong. And so regardless of the second category is handled a unification of all these under [specific-language](/questions/tagged/specific-language), would pollute it with incorrect questions.

I don't believe anyone wants this, and so I believe the addition of a new tag would solve this problem.

## Languages that most programmers wouldn't count as 'languages'

### Human languages

Human languages are not normally counted as a 'language'. And so if someone were to ask if asking if English is a language we support, tagging the question as [specific-language](/questions/tagged/specific-language) would be incorrect. This is because 'language' is a subset of language.

My preposed tag [language-scope](/questions/tagged/language-scope) is there to determine the scope of what *we* count as on-topic languages. Whilst this can be in short summed up as most programming languages.

This means the question [is legal code on-topic?](https://codereview.meta.stackexchange.com/q/6593) would not fit in [specific-language](/questions/tagged/specific-language) as it's not a 'language'. But I think we can all agree human languages are a language.

### Pseudocode

Pseudocode is the combination of human languages, programming languages and math into one language. This language comes in many dialects, for example I write pseudocode base heavily off Python. Pseudocode is widely used form of communication, however its large differences between dialects can make it seem like it's not a 'real' language.

Finally since it's unlikely to ever have a compiler/interpreter then the code is never going to be a 'language'.

### Unknown third party preprocessors

Most 'languages' are just third party preprocessors. You have your C that transpiles into assembly. You have TypeScript and JavaScript that transpile into JavaScript. You have your Java that transpiles into JVM bytecode.

A preprocessor makes you no longer program in the target language, however that doesn't make what your programming in a 'language'. Unlike pseudocode it has strict grammar and can become a 'language'. The only requirements for it becoming a 'language' is to have a name and for people to say it's a 'language'.

### UML - Unified Modelling Language

I don't think this needs to be explained.

### Git workflows

The way you interact with Git is through a shell and at least one program (git). All interactions are through a language, and you can make a complete script by just looking in your history. To say this isn't a language seems like a stretch. It's like saying REPLs stop the exchange from being classed as a language.

### CAD models

From my very basic knowledge these share similarities to [Scatch](https://codereview.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5923). They're structured and allow people to communicate. If I were to give a designer a CAD file they could determine what it is without me saying a single word. However if someone were to give me a CAD file I wouldn't be able to because I don't know the language.

This is as language is just an abstract form of communication. But what we class as 'languages' is much more narrow.

## Overall

I don't think we should tag human languages, pseudocode, 3rd-party preprocessors, UML, git workflows or CAD models as [specific-language](/questions/tagged/specific-language). Because for many on the site that just doesn't make sense. To many on this site these just aren't 'languages', but that doesn't make them not languages. Personally I don't aim to change how the tag is used now or or in the future.

I also don't think tagging "Is {collection of languages} on-topic?" as [specific-language](/questions/tagged/specific-language) is correct. As a collection is clearly not a specific language.

Adding a new tag solves both these problems and allows for easier and more correct searching. Don't want to know if a language is on-topic then just add `-[language-scope]` to your search. Want to know which specific 'languages' are on topic `[language-scope][specific-language]`.
And so I think adding a tag to determine the scope of all languages would be a benefit.

If we contrast this with Mast, then there would be *no way* to search for these questions. Even if we were to change specific-language to account for *all* languages then there would still be a gap. This is as asking if a collection of languages are on-topic would not be counted. Additionally I don't think we'll change [specific-language](/questions/tagged/specific-language) to account for all languages and so we'd be left with three groups that are all related but without a tag. This just makes the site harder to navigate.

TL;dr: In short adding the tag will allow *me* to more easily navigate the site. I cannot see how it harms the site.